# Port backend created in XAMPP to AWS server (EC2)

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, xampp

I am using AWS EC2 to create a back end for my website. I already have an AWS account and EC2 subscription.

I am familiar with LAMP and so am creating a database and some scripts locally using XAMPP. Now I want to know how I can port these to my AWS server. How do I upload script files to the server and how do I port the MySQL database to the EC2 instance?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the same as bringing up any server.  When you bring up your EC2 instance, you can use scp/WinSCP to transfer the files, then SSH to configure your server and database.

You must use something like an Elastic Block Store (to preserve your data).  When EC2 instances reboot, they reload from their S3 bucket, so any data that was on the local instance will be reset.  Therefore, your database must be on an external storage system.

This is a good resource:  http://www.livingdigitally.net/2009/04/tips-for-deploying-a-lamp-stack-on-amazon-ec2.html